# Trying implementing bootstrap confirm box on textbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

[Bootstrap confirmation]

Hi, I am new in bootstrap and having problem to implement bootstrap confirmation box on right side of type input control. In this scenario a user will get the confirmation box having ok/cancel button on each time tab off from the control.Please can somebody look into it?

please see the control:`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @id = "Email", maxlength = 100, autocomplete = "off", @Placeholder = "Email", @class = "text-lower" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)`

Please see below link for the reference.
[BootStrap confirmation](https://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#)

Answer (score 1):

> on each time tab off from the control

For this, you will have to hook an event of **[`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** on your textbox.

```
$("#Email").change(function(){
    // Whenever the value in the textbox changes this will be invoked.

    $("#yourelement").confirmation(options);
});
```

If you want to set the confirmation on the right side you will have to use `placement` in the `options` for the plugin setup.